# fan that require timers in the US

Tags: fans, laundry

About 6 years ago we did a remodel.  The electrician stated that a fan control was required in our laundry room, one of those things that looks like a dial and periodically turns on the fan.  I really hate the things, I can turn on the fan myself - and really it is never needed there.  But I digress -

Both fan countdown timers installed at that time are buzzing constantly and I need to replace them.  At the same time, I was thinking about just putting the fans on a z-wave controller and then I can schedule whatever I want - or even turn them on when away on vacation.

Roundabout, my question is this:  Are these kinds of timers (the round ones that click at certain times and turn the fan off and on) really required in a laundry area?  How about for a bathroom?  Would it be permissible to use a z-wave controlled switch instead?

Washington State, US.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No. Timers on exhaust fans are not required in a laundry area in Washington State, nor any other state, that I'm aware of.

If your z-wave switch is UL listed for fan control, then it's permissible.

This code excerpt makes no mention of specific rooms.

> 3. Local exhaust ventilation systems. Local exhaust **ventilation systems shall be controlled by manual switches, dehumidistats, timers, or other approved means.**
>
> (LOCAL EXHAUST. An exhaust system that uses one or more fans to exhaust air from a specific room or rooms within a dwelling.)
>
> –Chapter 51-52 WAC. STATE BUILDING CODE ADOPTION AND AMENDMENT OF THE 2015 EDITION OF THE INTERNATIONAL MECHANICAL CODE, [wa.gov](http://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&full=true)